# Possible directions in 3x3 matrix

Tags: matrices

I am trying to figure out the generation of a unique path in the grid-based system.
I came up with an idea to keep track of platforms place within a 3x3 matrix where 0 is an empty space and 1 is taken.

Example matrix:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Example matrix solution would be that I can move top, left and right.
In this case, let`s move to the left.
After the move is done matrix looks like this.

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

This is where I start to realize there should be a formula for this.
The next possible solutions are that we can move to the left or top because the right one is taken (we came from there) but the bottom one will create a loop path.

In the end, I am trying to create a path that does not create loops.

Additional case:
This also involves borders but that would be a less mathematical question I assume. But the idea would be to create a unique path without circles within a 10x10 (not set in stone) matrix.

I wonder if there is a formula for this that would be used to calculate the direction to move.
Any tips and help are much appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Matrix was shifted by the direction it is heading. Everything in the front is 0 (non-taken) and 1 represents taken spot. 
In my first matrix that is a start matrix where 1 represents taken and 0 non-taken spots in matrix. Moving in direction to the top in the first matrix it would stay the same because there is nothing at the sides, everything in the front is 0 where the 1s are moving.
Move persists of going in a direction (putting 1 at point 0) but I cannot create matrix something like this

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

where 4 spots are taken nearby.

Grid persists of 10x10 box filled with 0, then 1 is a taken place.

The end goal is making a unique path with 1 where it does not create loops by 4 taken spots by each other.

I am trying to find a math solution for creating a path that does not loop. Something like pathfinding but the key here is that I am trying to build the path with 10 taken spots rather then calculated best path from point A to point B.

Apologies if I made myself unclear. Hope this helps you to understand what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I do not understand what is happening. From where to where do you move? Why is the 3rd row 2nd column entry not taken anymore after you have moved?

Comment: @B.Swan I really do apologize for being such terrible on describing what I am looking for. I edited by adding additional information to understand what I am looking for. I do hope this help. Thank you for reading & trying to help me here.

Comment: I still do not understand what moving does. Are you moving inside the matrix? Are you moving the matrix over some bigger matrix? What exactly changes when you move? Take your start matrix, and show what moving in each direction does and why. Maybe show it also with another start matrix.